# List / Get post redirects

Tags: permalinks, redirect

In WordPress, when I change the slug of one of the posts, WordPress generally is able to automatically redirect it.

We're using WordPress as a backend for a SPA, and we aren't able to use these redirects.

Is there a way to get a list of all renamed pages with their correct permalink?

At present, I'm trying to look through the `posts` table to then compare revision `guid` attributes, but WordPress obviously is already doing something similar, so I'm hoping there is a function that I can use?

Any general pointers in the right direction would be appreciated, should I be looking for `revisions`, `posts` a field in the `options` table...